# BigInsights service in Bluemix is not showing up when trying to bind to an App

Tags: hadoop, analytics, ibm-cloud, biginsights

I have created 4 services in Bluemix,and one of them is the "Big Insights for Apache Hadoop". Now, when I try to Bind this to a newly created App, this BigInsights service is NOT showing up ? in "Add Service to "newly created app" window ?

Comment: As a followup - I deleted the earlier created BigInsights service, and tried to "Add" to the app, and I got a "This service doesn't support binding" ? popup.

Answer (score 0):

BigInsights for Apache Hadoop cannot be bound to an app before requesting and deploying a cluster.
You can request a cluster from the service administration page, using 'Launch' link.
Very important: Big Insights for Apache Hadoop is not provided for free, when requesting for a cluster you will send a subscription request.
Here you can find a complete tutorial about the steps to follow.
https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/BigInsights/index-gentopic1.html#provisioncluster

Comment: Thanks, and I requested a cluster but I am not sure of  a purchase as my project is on experimental basis.

Comment: @v.bontempi I have created cluster using the basic plan and it is shown in active stage. But still not able to bind to any app as it is not showing up. [link followed](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/BigInsights/index-gentopic5.html)